# How to check attribute of action from HttpRequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I've followed this [Prevent Forms authentication](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx) in order to try and handle redirecting from ajax gracefully.  However I need to be able to determine if certain attributes are decorating the action that this call was made for as I only want to do this for some occasions.  Can I get this information from the **HttpRequest** object that is accessible within this method?.

Essentially taking the part from the code above that I would like to manipulate:

```
public class SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirectModule : IHttpModule {

  private void OnPostReleaseRequestState(object source, EventArgs args) {
      var context = (HttpApplication)source;
      var response = context.Response;
      var request = context.Request; // request is HttpRequest

      if (response.StatusCode == 401 && request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == 
        "XMLHttpRequest") {

        // TODO HERE:  Check that the controller action contains a particular attribute
        //             and if so do not suppress redirect
        SuppressAuthenticationRedirect(context.Context);
      }
  }
  }
```

UPDATE:
It's probably worth noting that this code is held within a compiled DLL project that is then encorporated into a host MVC application (which we don't have access to).  In that case I don't really have access to changing default implementations unless I can ensure it doesn't effect the rest of the controllers in the application.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use as much of the framework as possible, which is why I chose to expose the GetControllerType method from the DefaultControllerFactory. You'll notice that routeData contains the area, controller and action, so with a bit of reflection, you can bypass having to create a derived controller factory.

This is definitely not production ready. It is just ***a*** way to get the custom attributes from the requested action.

**Edit**: instead of setting the current controller factory, create a new DerivedControllerFactory

```
var httpApplication = (HttpApplication)sender;
var httpContext = new HttpContext(httpApplication.Request, new HttpResponse(new StringWriter()));
var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));
//var factory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory() as DerivedControllerFactory;
var factory = new DerivedControllerFactory();
var controllerType = factory.GetControllerType(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext), routeData), routeData.Values["controller"].ToString());
var methodInfo = controllerType.GetMethod(routeData.Values["action"].ToString());
var attributes = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true);  

public class DerivedControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
   public new Type GetControllerType(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
   {
      return base.GetControllerType(requestContext, controllerName);
   }
}
```

Comment: Cheers Barry.  It definitely seems like an option.  Unfortunately this code is part of a shared application so I would be a bit weary of changing the default controller factory unless I could ensure it only effected the controllers I own.... I'm not sure if that's possible or not?

Comment: I modified the code above to avoid having to set the current controller factory.